# How to disable management endpoint probing with Spring Boot Admin?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

We are running Spring Boot Admin in our k8s cluster. Applications with SBA client library are discovered during startup and SBA(server) is calling management endpoint during specified interval. We are actually interested to only probe i.e `/health` and `/info` endpoint without `/actuator`.
Currently SBA is calling also management endpoint `/actuator`.

How to configure it to run server without calling management endpoint?

We would like to disable management endpoint for security purpose.

SBA Admin & SB version 2.6.6

I tried tweaking the settings but none of them solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`/actuator` is the "meta" endpoint providing information about the available actuator endpoints. But you cannot "manage" anything there. The [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.hypermedia) call it the "discovery page".

If you activate `health` and `info`, then `/actuator` will tell that these are enabled and output should be something like

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8100/actuator

{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8100/actuator",
      "templated": false
    },
    "health": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8100/actuator/health",
      "templated": false
    },
    "health-path": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8100/actuator/health/{*path}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "info": {
      "href": "http://127.0.0.1:8100/actuator/info",
      "templated": false
    }
  }
}
```

The SBA server uses this endpoint to know which actuators are available.

However, you can disable the endpoint in the monitored apps and everything should still work fine:

```
management.endpoints.web.discovery.enabled=false
```